# React-trancition-group. Transition does not work after migration from .v1 to .v2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-transition-group

I'm trying to migrate my app from old one to the new `React-trancition-group` API, but it's not so easy in case of using the manual `<Transition>` mode for transition creation of the particular React component.

My animation logic is:

we have an array of the components, each child of him comes one by one in the `<TransitionGroup>` API by `onClick` action. Where every new income component smoothly replace and hide previous one, which is already present in `<Transition>` API.

I almost finish unleash this tangle in `react-trancition-group` .v2, but one thing is still not solved - the component, that already been in `<Transition>` API does not disappear after the new one is overlayed him, which was automatically happen in `react-trancition-group` .v1 instead. So now they all just stack together...

So, maybe you can look on my code and luckly say where is my problem located...

I'll be grateful for any help. Thanks for your time

My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { findDOMNode } from 'react-dom'
import { TweenMax, Power1 } from 'gsap'
import { Transition } from 'react-transition-group'

class Slider extends Component {
  _onEntering = () => {
    const { id, getStateResult, isCurrentRow, removeAfterBorder, calcHeight } = this.props

    const el = findDOMNode(this)

    const height = calcHeight(el)

      TweenMax.set(el.parentNode, {
        height: `${height}px`
      })

      TweenMax.fromTo(
        el,
        0.5,
        {
          y: -120,
          position: 'absolute',
          width: `${100}%`,
          zIndex: 0 + id
        },
        {
          y: 0,
          width: `${100}%`,
          zIndex: 0 + id,
          ease: Power1.easeIn
        }
      )
  }

  _onEntered = () => {
    const { activeButton, removeAfterBorder, getCurrentOutcome } = this.props
    findDOMNode(this)
  }

  _onExiting = () => {
    const el = findDOMNode(this)

    TweenMax.to(el, 2, {
      onComplete: () => {
         el.className = ''
      }
    })
  }

  _onExited = () => {
    const { getStateResult } = this.props

    getStateResult(true)
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props

    return (
      <Transition
        in={true}
        key={id}
        timeout={2000}
        onEntering={() => this._onEntering()}
        onEntered={() => this._onEntered()}
        onExiting={() => this._onExiting()}
        onExited={() => this._onExited()}
        unmountOnExit
      >
        {children}
      </Transition> || null
    )
  }
}

export default Slider
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you problem is very typically. As you written here: `the component, that already been in <Transition> API does not disappear after the new one is overlayed him` - it's happen because you does not changing the status flag `in` for `Transition` Component. You set always `true` for him, it's not a right.

By the way, you need to understand what is you trying to do in your code. There is a big difference between methods `<Transition></Transition>` and `<TransitionGroup><CSSTransition></CSSTransition><TransitionGroup>`. You need to use pure `<Transition></Transition>` API only for very rare cases, when you need explicitly manipulate animation scenes.

As I see in you code you trying to replace one component by the other and in this case you need to use the second method that I have provided above.

So, try this:

```
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group'

  ...some code

return (
<TransitionGroup>
  <CSSTransition
    key={id}
    timeout={2000}
    onEntering={() => this._onEntering()}
    onEntered={() => this._onEntered()}
    onExiting={() => this._onExiting()}
    onExited={() => this._onExited()}
    unmountOnExit
  >
    {children}
  </CSSTransition> || null
</TransitionGroup>
)
```

It should help you and start to render Compenents by normal overlaying each other.